# Hibernate generate entity ID non-sequentially

Tags: database, hibernate

How can I generate IDs for object in a non-sequential manner? I would prefer for the IDs not to be a linear sequence and thus predictable. Yet, the generation strategies of `@GeneratedValue` are `AUTO, TABLE, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE`. Is there such (automatic) option? Or do I need to generate it myself? (And then check if such ID already exists etc.)

On this note, I feel that having a linear predictable IDs is not the ideal way. Am I correct? For instance, for resources like unlisted YouTube videos or sharing links from Google Drive it would be a big flaw to have the IDs sequentially as it would be really easy to iterate through them.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommended best-practice is to avoid exposing the internal primary key to external customers.  Besides the easily-guessed values you mentioned, it also makes it more difficult to consolidate databases later (such if you have multiple prod instances that you want to combine) or refactor the data design (in which case the current primary key is no longer valid/useful/whatever).

If you keep the ID within your local app, then using a sequential PK is just fine because it's only used within the database, and it's a common approach in many RDBMs.

Now you need a business-derived unique identifier to be able to pull up the specific XYZ that a consumer might want.  Can be single or multiple columns, but its meaning needs to have business meaning more than database meaning, if that makes sense.  Personally, I like using GUIDs/UUIDs because, though theoretically possible, very rarely do you have overlaps (depends on the implementation however).  However, you might not want to use GUIDs as your PK because then there's a lot more bytes involved with FK relationships, whereas an integer is substantially smaller.

If you really want to use a non-sequential ID that could be used by a consumer, it might be possible to create a database view that does some randomization and use that as the table in the @GeneratedValue (disclaimer: I've never done anything like that, I've always used sequence generators, but theoretically it might work).